# Android - Count number of .mp3 in raw

Tags: android, count

Inside of `res/raw` I have 3 .mp3 files, `clip1.mp3` , `clip2.mp3`, and `clip3.mp3`.

Inside of my service application I am trying to count the number of files in the `res/raw` directory.

```
R.raw.class.getFields().length; // returns 5 instead of 3
```

If I try to remove them all from the directory to test if it returns 0, `R.raw` is no longer recognized as a symbol (even though I haven't deleted the folder, only it's contents).

I searched for hidden files in the folder (Windows 10), none exist.

Is there a reason the line above returns 5? Or is there a way to specifically count just the number of `.mp3` files? Those are the only extensions I'm interested in.

**EDIT:**

It turns out there are files I can't see in Windows10. I looped through the directory and logged all of the assets inside of the folder:

```
  Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
            for (int count = 0; count < fields.length; count++)
            {
                Log.i("Raw Asset: ", fields[count].getName());
            }
```

and got this output:

```
11-27 02:36:09.392 8363-8375/com.audioserver:remote I/Raw Asset:: $change
11-27 02:36:09.392 8363-8375/com.audioserver:remote I/Raw Asset:: clip1
11-27 02:36:09.392 8363-8375/com.audioserver:remote I/Raw Asset:: clip2
11-27 02:36:09.392 8363-8375/com.audioserver:remote I/Raw Asset:: clip3
11-27 02:36:09.392 8363-8375/com.audioserver:remote I/Raw Asset:: serialVersionUID
```

How do I exclude `$change` and `serialVersionUID` from my return value?

Answer (score 1):

```
Start in count=1 avoid $change & avoid serialVersionUID with an if

  Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
            for (int count = 1; count < fields.length; count++)
            {
               if (!fields[count].getName().equals("serialVersionUID")) {
                Log.i("Raw Asset: ", fields[count].getName());
               }
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please feel free to take a [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site, and if you need additional help with the site, check [this](//stackoverflow.com/help) out. Oh, and if you ever run into issues that the help page doesn't cover, feel free to ask on [meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!